# generate pdf from text file in python

Tags: python, pdf, module, text-processing, reportlab

Is there a solution to create pdf file from txt, maybe in ReportLab? To produce like this

```
+------+-------+------------+
| Name |  Age  |  Nickname  |
+======+=======+============+
| 107  |  Ella | Fitzgerald |
+------+-------+------------+
| 108  | Louis | Armstrong  |
+------+-------+------------+
| 109  | Miles |   Davis    |
+------+-------+------------+
| 110  | Benny |  Goodman   |
+------+-------+------------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReportLab is an option. LaTeX is another option.

Comment: yes I already test the Reportlab, but is there any sample of source to import the whole text files into pdf? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

EMACS org mode make this task exceedingly simple. Org makes it easy to format tables in plain ASCII. Any line with ‘|’ as the first non-whitespace character is considered part of a table. ‘|’ is also the column separator.

C-c C-e p     (org-export-as-pdf)
    Export as LaTeX and then process to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Pisa generates from html. It's very easy to use.

http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/
http://www.20seven.org/journal/2008/11/pdf-generation-with-pisa-in-django.html
http://antydba.blogspot.com/search/label/django%20pisa%20html2pdf%20polskie%20czcionki

```
import ho.pisa as pisa
import cStringIO as StringIO

result = StringIO.StringIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO("<table><tr><td>test test</td></tr></table>"), result)
```

Comment: according to [link](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf) Python, virtualenv and dependencies

    **Install Python 2.6.x or 2.7.x. Installation steps depends on yours operating system.** I am currently using Python 2.5.x